# Unable to resolve "../../App" from "node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js"?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, native

I am facing Unable to resolve "../../App" from "node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js"?

Mine project has

```
"sdk Version": "38.0.0",
"expo": "^38.0.10",
"react-native": "0.59.10",


I am using react native version 0.59 and i have created app.json and put extensions in it as given in previous solutions but not working . Kindly help
```

Comment: How does your AppEntry.js looks like? also what is inside your app.js

Comment: I hadn't made App.js I am using screen.js as my root file

Comment: dude .. just show me your appEntry js pls edit your question

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a metro bundler issue.

`https://github.com/GeekyAnts/vue-native-core/issues/117#issuecomment-520403713`

This this.

Comment: No I had done this by creating app.json and also created App entry.js but nothing happened .